# Slow booting time/startup time in kali linux (KDE Plasma)

Tags: kali-linux, gnome, kde, dual-boot, startup

I recently set up a dual boot kali linux with Windows 11 on my Acer Predator. It has a 16 GB RAM, 4 GB graphics card. Kali linux is installed on the 1 TB HDD on a 100 GB partition. The desktop environment I installed is KDE Plasma. I have used live USB before but I am fairly new to linux.

After I enter my password, it takes more than 2 minutes for the desktop environment to load, during which I just see a black screen with a logo on it (of KDE Plasma).

1. Is this because of KDE Plasma? (I can switch to GNOME)
2. Is this because of something else?

I can provide more information about my setup if required.

Comment: See Gordon's comment to your newer question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736960/slow-wi-fi-speed-on-kali-linux#comment1399497_736960 you're really using a platform that makes your life unnecessarily hard. Even the intended audience of Kali - experienced Linux users doing penetration testing - will use the right tool at the right time, and here, Kali is clearly not the right tool. You want an everyday Linux, not a pentesting Linux.

Comment: The biggest improvement to boot time on your computer would be achieved by switching from an HDD to a SSD. However if you cannot do that I’d recommend you install LXQt (not Gnome). As mentioned above Kali is not the best for new Linux users. If you replace it with Lubuntu you will get LXQt on Ubuntu which is a sound choice

Comment: note twice that Kali is a pentesting distro. installing a fancier, much-automatic-network-transactions involved desktop environment such as KDE is explicitly on the things *not to do on Kali*.