# Slow wi-fi speed on kali linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, iwlwifi

I have a dual boot kali linux installation. On checking my wifi speed on https://speedtest.net/ , I am getting 50 - 100 Mbps. But, even basic webpages are not loading smoothly on the kali linux. Note that on Windows, the same webpages and downloads proceed much faster.

I am new to linux, so I don't know much about this. I have an Intel chipset that uses `iwlwifi` wifi drivers. I can provide additional information that is needed.

Comment: If you're new to linux, I'd recommend avoiding kali. It's intended for expert users (especially those working in network security), and is (intentionally) a lot less user-friendly than most other distros. See ["Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?"](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/5361#5361)

Comment: Plus, Kali is especially not meant for smooth and fast wireless - its whole thing is that it disables all network automatisms that might accidentally make your presence known; which conveniently means that running a Speedtest is about as far as it gets from the intended use case of Kali. Try something other than Kali first - Ubuntu it Linux mint for example - and if things are still slow on that, then we at least have a data point that tells us what to not look into

Comment: There's only one data point here. What speed is your Internet connection? What does "_downloads proceed much faster_" actually mean in numbers?

Comment: @roaima My internet speed as mentioned is generally 50 to 100 Mbps. On speedtest, it does show the same speed, but while actually downloading, I don't even 500 Kbps speed on my kali linux.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I needed to install kali linux for an assignment which involved using some network security tools. I wanted to get a working linux dual boot since a long time, so I thought of using this as my main linux platform instead of using kali off the USB, and then again setting up a new install for Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Kali isn't intended to be used as a main platform at all. It's not a desktop distribution, a LOT of things are _intentionally_  "broken" in the sense of desktop use; e.g. network services are [disabled by default](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/). It's a toolset, and the professionals who actually use it mostly don't run it on hardware but use it as a VM or from a USB stick. I'd suggest doing the same; use a desktop distro as a daily driver (I'd recommend plain old Debian as Kali's built on that) and download appropriate VM from Kali site.

Comment: I hope you get the point that nobody's dissing you for using Kali. But a big part of performing a task is using a the correct tool for the task in the way it's intended to be used. "Why is internetting with Kali so slow" is akin to "Why is cooking rice with my coffeemaker so slow" :-) - it *can* be done, but *should* it? Due to its nature Kali is built to be extremely secure, and browsing the internet is by its very nature extremely *in*secure activity.

Comment: Please put your speeds into the question. At the moment it reads you're only getting 50-100 Mb/s on Kali, with no other information